# Mi contador no incremnta al usarlo

Tags: c++, dev-c++, contador

Mi código ya cumple con su función de guardar los datos ingresados la primera vez pero al hacerlo por segunda vez me doy cuenta que el contador llamado contadorPrincipal encargado de asignar la casilla donde se guarda el dato ingresado no incrementa su valor, ya que le coloque se imprima su valor para verificarlo en un modulo aparte para evitar conflictos y con  este modulo veo se queda estable en 1 por mas veces que se le llame a su modulo haciendo que no se guarde mas que el registro no.1, alguien me podría ayudar del por que pasa esto por favor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class individuo{
    private:
        string nombre[99];
        string apellidosPats[99];   
        string apellidosMats[99];
        string fechasNacs[99];
        string nacionalidades[99];
        string alturas[99];
        string pesos[99];
        string edades[99];
        int contadorPrincipal,j;
        public: /*Set para establecer valor    Get para el valor almacenado*/
            void setNombre(){ /*Obtiene el teclado desde el nombre*/
                cout<<"Introduzca el nombre"<<endl;
                cin>>nombre[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setapellidoPat(){
                cout<<"Introduzca el apellido paterno"<<endl;
                cin>>apellidosPats[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setapellidoMat(){
                cout<<"Introduzca el apellido materno"<<endl;
                cin>>apellidosMats[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setfechaNac(){
                cout<<"Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento en DD/MM/AAAA"<<endl;
                cin>>fechasNacs[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setnacionalidad(){
                cout<<"Introduzca su nacionalidad"<<endl;
                cin>>nacionalidades[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setaltura(){
                cout<<"Introduzca su altura como el sig ejemplo:172"<<endl;
                cin>>alturas[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setpeso(){
                cout<<"Introduzca su peso como el sig ejemplo: 80"<<endl;
                cin>>pesos[contadorPrincipal];
            }
            void setedad(){
                cout<<"Introduzca su edad como el sig ejemplo:19"<<endl;
                cin>>edades[contadorPrincipal]; 
            }
            void contador(){
                contadorPrincipal++;
                cout<<"contador1->"<<contadorPrincipal<<endl;
            }
            void registro(){
                j=0;
                for(int i=0;i<contadorPrincipal;i++){
                cout<<"Posicion "<<i<<"->"<<"Nombre:"<<nombre[i]<<" "<<apellidosPats[i]<<" "<<apellidosMats[i]<<endl;
                }
                cout<<"Ingrese el numero de posicion del usuario que desea ver su registro->";
                cin>>j;
                cout<<"Nombre:"<<nombre[j]<<" "<<apellidosPats[j]<<" "<<apellidosMats[j]<<endl;
                cout<<"Feha de nacimiento:"<<fechasNacs[j]<<endl;
                cout<<"Nacionalidad:"<<nacionalidades[j]<<endl;
                cout<<"Edad:"<<edades[j]<<endl;
                cout<<"Peso:"<<pesos[j]<<endl;
                cout<<"Altura:"<<alturas[j]<<endl;
            }
};
int main(){
    int con=0,contador2=0;
    individuo persona[99];
    do{
        persona[contador2].setNombre();
        persona[contador2].setapellidoPat();
        persona[contador2].setapellidoMat();
        persona[contador2].setfechaNac();
        persona[contador2].setnacionalidad();
        persona[contador2].setaltura();
        persona[contador2].setpeso();
        persona[contador2].setedad();
        persona[contador2].contador();
        if(contador2<99){
        cout<<"¿Desea agregar otro registro?     1=si     0=no"<<endl;
        cin>>con;
        contador2++;
        }
        else con=0;
        if(con==0){
            con=0;
        do{
        cout<<"¿Desea ver el registro de alguna persona?   1=si    0=no"<<endl;
        cin>>con;
        if(con!=0){
            cout<<" "<<endl;
            persona[0].registro();
        }
        } while(con!=0);
        }
    } while(con!=0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que he entendido al leer tu codigo es que lo que quieres hacer es crear 99 `individuo` y lo que has planteado es alamcenarlo en un array en el `main`

En la variable `persona` vas a guardar 99 objetos de tipo `individuo`, cada uno de estos objetos tiene los siguientes atributos:

```cpp
string nombre[99];
        string apellidosPats[99];   
        string apellidosMats[99];
        string fechasNacs[99];
        string nacionalidades[99];
        string alturas[99];
        string pesos[99];
        string edades[99];
```

Y creo que a ti te interesa que la clase `persona` no contenga arrays de `string`
ya que en cada instancia de esa clase guardarás solo 1 `string`

Haciendolo así:

- `persona[0]` tiene la variable `apellidosPats` que guarda 99 `strings` *(junto a todas las demás)*
- `persona[1]` tiene la variable `apellidosPats` que guarda 99 `strings` *(junto a todas las demás)*
- `persona[2]` tiene la variable `apellidosPats` que guarda 99 `strings` *(junto a todas las demás)*
- `...`

Tu accedes a los metodos de `persona[N]`y haces tus cambios e incrementas el contador, pero cuando accedes a otra persona, los atributos no son los mismos entre `persona[M]` y `persona[N]`

El contador incrementa en cada persona. Decirte que cuando creas *(instancias)*
un objeto de tipo `persona` no defines el contador a `0`.

```cpp
int main(){
    /* Las tres variables son zonas de memoria distintas y con
     *  distintos atributos.
     */
    individuo personaUno;
    individuo personaDos;
    individuo personaTres;
   
    personaUno.contador(); //  Incrementa la variable de personaUno e imprime su valor
    personaUno.contador();

    personaDos.contador(); //  Incrementa la variable de personaDos e imprime su valor

    /* Tiene sentido que cuando se impriman 
     * los valores de los dos objetos sea distintos valores 
     */

}
```

Si entiendes como funcionan los objetos te resultará sencillo entener el problema, mi modificación a tu clase `individuo` sería lo siguiente

```cpp
class individuo{
    private:
        string nombre, apellidoPat, apellidoMat, fechaNac, nacionalidad;
        ...


      public:
            void setNombre(){
                cout<<"Introduzca el nombre"<<endl;
                cin>>nombre;
            }
            string getNombre(){
                return nombre;
            }
            ...

};
int main(){
    int personaActual = 0;
    individuo totalPersonas[99];
    do{
        totalPersonas[personaActual].setNombre();
        totalPersonas[personaActual].setapellidoPat();
        totalPersonas[personaActual].setapellidoMat();
        totalPersonas[personaActual].setfechaNac();
        ...

        personaActual++;

}
```